# When files have to be saved to database?

Tags: database, file

The images and documents could be saved to filesystem or database. For example I can save it to byte array and store in database or I can save it to filesystem and get an url. So when files are saved to database and when to filesystem? Or sometimes both? What is the best method to store files?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a system to save files to, as the name suggests, I would look into a "filesystem". A Database CAN hold files, but for most purposes this is just useless.

You *can* save the location (directory, name/hash, etc) in a database, but just save your file on a filesystem. Databases are good in a lot of things, but saving files isn't specifically it.

Of course, if you documents are pure tekst, it might be better to save them to a database, e.g. elasticsearch, so you can do a search, but these are special cases: you're not talking about saving files, you're talking about searching, for which you accidentally find a different way to save the file.